# How to obtain non-uniformly scrolling elements and layered "curtain-like" backgrounds on a webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm talking about websites like [this FullToss one](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/zones/fulltoss/index.html) and [this ASUS one](http://eee.asus.com/en/transformer-300/features).

I'm fascinated by how each of the floated elements seems to be scrolling at a different pace. And how the backgrounds appear to be layered and rise like curtains, hiding previously visible elements, and revealing new ones, as the user scrolls down or up the page.

I'm just not able to get my head around writing CSS/jQUery to achieve this effect. Any help, or a tiny working example would help!

**EDIT :**
Thanks to Andrew and sevenseacat for pointing me to the "parallax" effect. I now know that [several websites use it](http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html), including [this insane one that loops around scrolling](http://unfold.no/), and [this Range Rover site that doesn't even have a scrollbar](https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT)!

I've accepted Scott's answer since it directly answers my question, but thanks to Andrew too for directing me to more resources.

Comment: That is a parallax effect.

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'parallax' - that might help your searching endeavours.

Comment: @sevenseacat: Great! Thanks for the keyword I was missing! I found plenty of 'parallax' resources, and [this very nice tutorial on net.tuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the source code for the first link, it appears to be using one main JQuery plugin to handle the scroll event - Parallax. http://stephband.info/jparallax/. This allows the developer to set the scroll speed for different parts of the page relative to the normal scroll event. The following code is an excerpt from the first link that should provide some context to what is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
//xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
//inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
//outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
$('#first').parallax("25%", 0.1);
$('.ft1-small-1-bg').parallax("75%", 0.4);
$('.ft1-small-2-bg').parallax("75%", 0.2);

$('#second').parallax("25%", 0.1);
$('.ft2-small-1-bg').parallax("100%", 0.4);
$('.ft2-small-2-bg').parallax("100%", 0.2);

$('#third').parallax("50%", 0.3);
$('.ft3-small-1-bg').parallax("100%", 0.4);
$('.ft3-small-2-bg').parallax("100%", 0.2);

$('#fourth').parallax("50%", 0.3);
$('.ft4-small-1-bg').parallax("10%", 0.4);
$('.ft4-small-2-bg').parallax("10%", 0.2);
$('.ft4-small-3-bg').parallax("110%", 0.2);
$('.ft4-small-4-bg').parallax("110%", 0.2);

$('.tabs-menu a').fttabs();

var viewportHeight = screen.height;
var headerHeight = $('.fulltoss-header').outerHeight();
var vheight = viewportHeight-headerHeight;
$('#fourth.page').height(vheight);
$('#fourth .story').css('height',vheight);
$('#fourth .story').css('min-height',vheight);
$('#fourth .story').css('overflow','hidden');
$('.ft4-small-1-bg, .ft4-small-2-bg, .ft4-small-3-bg, .ft4-small-4-  bg').height(vheight);
});
```

source - http://www.espncricinfo.com/navigation/zones/fulltoss/main.js?10

Answer (score 0):

Here is some decent parallax library that you can use:

- [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)
- [jparallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)
- [Jarallax](https://github.com/CodeHunger/Jarallax)

If you have a good look around Google, you will find a range of different ones.

Comment: Superscrollorama is simply awesome!!

Comment: There is a good few interesting once out there. Its worth having a good play around with some of them and using the one that you think fits your needs the best. good luck

Comment: Thanks! Btw, you mean interesting *ones! ;)